# Laravel controller, move creating and updating to model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

my question is about how to split this code. I have a registration form and it's saving function looks like this:

```
public function store(EntityRequestCreate $request)
{
    $geoloc = new Geoloc;
    $geoloc->lat = $request->input('lat');
    $geoloc->lng = $request->input('lng');
    $geoloc->slug = $request->input('name');
    $geoloc->save();

    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $entity = new Entity;
    $entity->name = $request->input('name');
    $entity->type = $request->input('type');
    $entity->email = $request->input('email');
    $entity->tags = $request->input('tags');
    $entity->_geoloc()->associate($geoloc);
    $entity->save();

    $entity_id = $entity->id;

    $address = new Address;
    $address->building_name = $request->input('building_name');
    $address->address = $request->input('address');
    $address->town = $request->input('town');
    $address->postcode = $request->input('postcode');
    $address->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
    $address->entity_id = $entity_id;
    $address->save();

    $role = User::find($user_id);
    $role->role = "2";
    $role->save();

    DB::table('entity_user')->insert(array('entity_id' =>  $entity_id, 'user_id' => $user_id));

    $result = $geoloc->save();
    $result2 = $entity->save();
    $result3 = $address->save();
    $result4 = $role->save();

    if ($result && $result2 && $result3 && $result4) {
        $data = $entity_id;
    }
    else {
        $data = 'error';
    }

    return redirect('profile/entity');
}
```

As you see, it has a custom request and it is saving to 3 models, that way my controller code is far too long (having many other functions etc) Instead I want to move this code to a model, as my model so far has only relationships defined in it. However I don't exactly know how to call a model from controller, do I have to call it or it will do it automatically? Any other ideas on how to split the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the models [`create`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) method to make this code shorter and more readable.

For example:

```
$geoloc = Geoloc::create(
    $request->only(['lat', 'lng', 'name'])
);

$entity = Entity::create(
    $request->only(['name', 'type', 'email', 'tags])
);
$entity->_geoloc()->associate($geoloc);

$address = Address::create([
    array_merge(
        ['entity_id' => $entity->id],
        $request->only(['building_address', 'address', 'town'])
    )
])

...
```

The `create` method will create an object from a given associated array. The `only` method on the request object will return an associated array with only the fields for the given keys.

Comment: I would still like to use model more, at the moment I feel I am not using it's 'space' , only defining it for relationships, is there any way if I could use that code in model?